# RuntimeException in HttpPost(String) Construct Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http-post

I am attempting to upload a file from an Android client application to a Google App Engine Blobstore. I am using the HttpPost class with a MultipartEntityBuilder to do so. My code is experiencing a RuntimeException at the construction of the HttpPost class. The App Engine is quered for an upload Url which I am supposed to then POST my file to. My code looks somewhat as follows:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
  builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
  builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file)); //file is a File type member of the class
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); //RuntimeException occurrs here

  ...
}
```

The "url" variable (which is the upload url) looks something like this:

```
http://myappengine.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bAk5dJbfPLqzYjsEjg/ALBNUaYAJavGsaScLq/
```

and it appears to be valid (when I copy/paste the url into my browser I just get a blank page, no errors or anything). I am absolutely clueless as to what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace from logcat.

Comment: According to javadocs it throws IllegalArgumentException if the uri is invalid.  Is this what you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the trailing slash on the Url, getting rid of that made it work (despite the trailing slash being returned and working in browswer).